# Bayesian Experiment Design Resources

Tags: bayesian, references, experiment-design

I'm interested in exploring experiment design and analysis therein through the Bayesian lens. I haven't seen much content here; it would seem that Bayesians are more concentrated in analysis of observation studies rather than RCT.

Could any books, courses, YT playlists be recommended that discuss experiment design through the Bayesian lens?

Comment: can you be a little bit more precise about the types of experiments your interested in? You are correct that the classical approaches to the design of physical experiments are frequentist; however, the design of computer experiments tends to be rather Bayesian.

Comment: Sure— typically related to supply chain networks. So a treatment might include a different mechanism by which demand is forecasted, a change to truck load size or frequency of deliveries and the response variable is network health metrics like back order rate

Comment: It's somewhat ambiguous how you phrased the question. If you're interested in how Bayesian think about _trial design_ I recommend starting with [this presentation by Frank Harrell](https://youtu.be/GPcaum9rlKw). But if you're interested in how Bayesians use _observational data_ to infer causal effects otherwise needing RCTs, start with [this talk by Kay Brodersen](https://youtu.be/GTgZfCltMm8).

Comment: Have a look at Chapter 7, Experimental design, in the book by [Sivia](https://www.amazon.com/Data-Analysis-Bayesian-Devinderjit-Sivia/dp/0198568320/ref=sr_1_1?crid=2TYFD17B4179D&keywords=sivia&qid=1683905250&s=books&sprefix=siria%2Cstripbooks-intl-ship%2C155&sr=1-1).

Comment: @RomkeBontekoe- this http://aprsa.villanova.edu/files/sivia.pdf? This model design seems very specific to the author’s problem